# MacOSX Server - Enrollment

Tags: objective-c, mdm, osx-server

I have problem with clean installation of MacOS X Server. I can't use Enroll button in devices page. Err 500. Log from server:

```
0:: [8047] [2015/11/16 18:14:01.678] <85.93.120.195> Completed in 253ms | 500 Internal Server Error  [https://osx.bcas.cz/devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_enroll]
1:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.432] <85.93.120.195> Time since script start: 8525us [https://osx.bcas.cz/devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_enroll]
1:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.432] <85.93.120.195> >>> Processing POST mdm_enroll
1:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.551] <85.93.120.195> iOS version 9.1
1:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.561] \033[1;7;31mEXCEPTION:\033[0;31m  Error <-[SCEPHelper getSCEPRootCertificateForHost:] (/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/RemoteDeviceManagement/RemoteDeviceManagement-889.8/Compiled/Framework-Base/Support/SCEPHelper.m:89): "'((SCEPHELPER_GetSCEPRootCertificate(self.connection, hostname, hostnameCnt, &root, &rootCnt)))' error 1">
    USERINFO: {
        NSLocalizedDescription = "Operation not permitted";
    }\033[0m\033[0m
0:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.561] do_dmx_get_scep_root_certificate: caught exception -[SCEPHelper getSCEPRootCertificateForHost:] (/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/RemoteDeviceManagement/RemoteDeviceManagement-889.8/Compiled/Framework-Base/Support/SCEPHelper.m:89): "'((SCEPHELPER_GetSCEPRootCertificate(self.connection, hostname, hostnameCnt, &root, &rootCnt)))' error 1"
0:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.561] <85.93.120.195> EXCEPTION: 500 Internal Server Error - Could not retrieve root certificate from open directory server. at
    #0 /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/php/ota_service_common.php(43): DieInternalError('Could not retri...')
    #1 /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/php/mdm_enroll.php(78): GenerateMDMBindingProfile(8191, '6EBF7885-74A7-4...')
    #2 {main}
1:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.562] <85.93.120.195> <<< Sent Final Output (26 bytes) - POST mdm_enroll
0:: [7664] [2015/11/16 18:14:13.562] <85.93.120.195> Completed in 138ms | 500 Internal Server Error  [https://osx.bcas.cz/devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_enroll]
```

I tried remove and add certificates, restart server app and restart server and others from google and nothing work. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What certificates did you remove? You may need to reset OD. It creates a couple certificates that look like currently don't exist.

> EXCEPTION: 500 Internal Server Error - Could not retrieve root
>   certificate from open directory server